# How delete object from array in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

i using MongoDb and NodeJs and i have a little problem with deleting object from array of objects. Here is my code

```
router.route('/deleteGuestFromJam/:id').delete(function(req, res){

Jam.find({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, jam){

    jam.guests = _.without(jam.guests, _.findWhere(jam.guests, {id: req.user.id}));

    jam.save(function(err, jam) {
        if (err){
            return res.status(500).send(err)
        }
        console.log(jam.guests)
        return res.status(200).send(jam);
    });

})
```

And when i call this route the console give me "jam.save is not a function" error. Someone can explain me why is it happening ?. Thx for answers

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to have any connection to the actual question you're asking at the end of your post.  Please fix the title to match the subject of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use update like this

```
Jam.update({_id: req.params.id}, 
    { $pull: { 
           guests: { 
                  $elemMatch: { id: req.user.id } 
           } 
       } 
     }, function(){....});
```

It will pull out the matched object from quests array.
See mongo docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)